# Placing setTimeout within setTimeout with an if condition

Tags: javascript

I have two setTimouts as below, according to an `if` condition, i want to skip one timeout.

```
var batchID = [];

batchID = getBatchIDs();//this function gets me the batch IDs
setTimeout(function() {
    //I get the batchIDs in the first 30 seconds.
    //here i want to put a check, if(batchID.length === 2)
    //{I want the script to wait for another 50 seconds} 
    //else {proceed with func1 and func2}
    setTimeout(function() {
        func1();
        func2();
    }, 50000);
},30000);
```

So is this the correct way of doing it :

```
setTimeout(function() {
    if(batchID.length === 2) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            func1();
            func2();
        }, 50000);
    } else {
        func1();
        func2();
    };
},30000);
```

As I have a lot of code in place of `func1()` and `func2()`. So just wondering if i have to repeat it or I can use some other logic.

thank you.

Comment: why don't you take advantage of promises and anonymous done functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the delay of the timeout, depending on your condition:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var delay = (batchID.length === 2) ? 50000 : 0;
    setTimeout(function() {
        func1();
        func2();
    }, delay);
},30000);
```

If `batchID.length === 2`, the timeout will run in 50 seconds, otherwise, it will fire asap.

I used a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), here:

```
var delay = (batchID.length === 2) ? 50000 : 0;
```

This is short-hand for:

```
var delay;
if(batchID.length === 2){
    delay = 50000;
} else {
    delay = 0;
}
```